# Can we bind image component source through programming?

Tags: media-library, components

We would like to bind image component src thorough programming and would like to get Hash value as well.

Need this output :

```
<img src="/-/XXXXXX?h=192&amp;w=192&amp;hash=98HGR761E4B00739EF6E206F74C443AE" alt="Two people working" width="192" height="192" data-variantitemid="{KH6HFU6F-KUT2-452B-B519-D60393CB1F56}" data-variantfieldname="Image">
```

We are getting data from `content api` and bind them on a view. However, when we are trying to bind data for the image , we are not able  to get above mentioned attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to call `Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl`:

```
var url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem, options);
var protectedUrl = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(url);
```

This will calculate the hash value based on the parameters from the url.

Comment: I will try this and can we bind image component src with custom url ?

Comment: You should add your code to the question. It's not clear how you work with images and api.